Uniform Integrability Alternative Proof
There is a fact on uniform integrability from Amir Dembo's notes:

If $|X_\alpha|\leq Y$ for all $\alpha$ and some R.V. $Y$ such that $\mathbb{E}Y<\infty$, then the collection $\{X_\alpha\}$ is uniformly integrable. In particular, any finite collection of integrable R.V. is UI.

Recall Uniform Integrability:
A possibly uncountable collection of R.V.s $\{X_\alpha: \alpha\in I\}$ is uniformly integrable if
$$\lim\limits_{M\rightarrow\infty} \sup\limits_{\alpha}\mathbb{E}\left[|X_\alpha|{\bf{1}}_{|X_\alpha| > M}\right]=0$$
I came up with this proof, but I would appreciate a second pair of eyes to critque it. In particular I'm unsure whether my choice of random variables does converge almost surely to $0$ and whether the conclusion I reached with the DCT is correct.
For each $M$, select an index $\alpha_M$ such that
$$\sup\limits_\alpha \mathbb{E}\left[|X_\alpha|{\bf{1}}_{|X_{\alpha}|>M}\right]< \mathbb{E}\left[|X_{\alpha_M}|{\bf{1}}_{|X_{\alpha_M}|>M}\right]+\frac{1}{2^M}\quad (1)$$
Note that as $M\rightarrow0$, the sequence $|X_{\alpha_M}|{\bf{1}}_{X_{\alpha_M}>M}$ approaches almost surely to $X(\omega)=0$.  From the hypothesis, $|X_{\alpha_M}|{\bf{1}}_{|X_{\alpha_M}|>M}\leq |X_{\alpha_M}|\leq Y$, the Dominated Convergence Theorem implies
$$\mathbb{E}\left[|X_{\alpha_M}|{\bf{1}}_{|X_{\alpha_M}|>M}\right]\rightarrow0$$
as $M\rightarrow \infty$. Using the upper bound above, we have $$\lim\limits_{M\rightarrow\infty}\sup\limits_\alpha\mathbb{E}\left[|X_\alpha|{\bf{1}}_{|X_\alpha|>M}\right]=\lim\limits_{M\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{E}\left[|X_{\alpha_M}|{\bf{1}}_{|X_{\alpha_M}|>M}\right]+\frac{1}{2^M}=0$$

Why can't you just use the fact that $|X_{\alpha}|\mathbf{1}{|X{\alpha}|>M}\leq Y\mathbf{1}{Y>M}$? Just notice that ${|X{\alpha}|>M}\subseteq {Y>M}$. Now show that $E\bigg(|Y|\mathbf{1}_{{Y>M}}\bigg)\xrightarrow{M\to\infty}0$. You can use DCT to show this.

Yes true. This was the first step in the notes, and I was about to show the rest with DCT. The posted proof was my first attempt before reading it, so I'm wondering if missed something.

You have not missed anything but you would want to make it explicitly clear that the convergence does not depend on the choice of $\alpha$. i.e. for a given $\epsilon$, you want to choose $M$ such that $\frac{1}{2^{M}}<\epsilon$ and so is $E(|X_{\alpha_{M}}\mathbf{1}{|X{\alpha_{M}}>M}<\epsilon$ for all $M\geq M_{0}$ but this choice of $M_{0}$ should not depend on the index $\alpha_{M}$.

You would want to make sure that the choice of $M_{0}$ comes from chosing $M_{0}$ such that $M\geq M_{0}\implies E(Y\mathbf{1}{Y>M})<\epsilon$ since  $E(Y\mathbf{1}{Y>M})$ is larger than $E(|X_{\alpha_{M}}|\mathbf{1}{X{\alpha_{M}}>M})$.

But why would the choice of the indices be problematic here? If we find one (which does exists) such sequence of indices where the $(1)$ holds and apply the squeeze theorem, doesn't convergence follow?
